# How to Change "Text" On All Specific Class Column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML table and javascript like this:

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("td.status");

if(x[0].textContent = "3")
{
    x[0].textContent = "Declined"
}
else if(x[0].textContent = "2")
{
    x[0].textContent = "Approved"
}
else
{
    x[0].textContent = "Pending"
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>2016-10-11 13:10:26</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>mail@yahoo.com</td>
        <td>number</td>
        <td class="status" value="3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2016-10-11 13:10:26</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>mail@yahoo.com</td>
        <td>number</td>
        <td class="status" value="2">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2016-10-11 13:10:26</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>mail@yahoo.com</td>
        <td>number</td>
        <td class="status" value="0">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I run the code, the result only affected the first row of the table.

The question is, how to make the javascript code to replace the text in class `status` with given statement when pages get loaded:

3 = Declined
2 = Approved
0 = Pending

Comment: Do you understand what that javascript code does? If you do, you can modify it with a loop and maybe a switch-case to do what you need. If you don't you need to figure that out and learn.

Comment: @Esko, I'm not very good at javascript, because of that, I can't solve this puzzle. Please help or give more hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for loop

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("td.status");
for(var i=0 ; i < x.length; i++ ) {
    if(x[i].textContent == "3"){
      x[i].textContent = "Declined"
  } 
  else if(x[i].textContent == "2"){
      x[i].textContent = "Approved"
   }
 else {
   x[i].textContent = "Pending"
 }
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for solving this simple puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

the if condition is not correct, one = is used for assignment, == is used for comparison

so in your case, your if conditions must look like this

```
if(x[0].textContent == "3")
```

Comment: Thanks sir, you make me realize my mistake there.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to iterate, as it's tagged with jQuery, you can let it do everything for you

```js
$('td.status').text(function(_, txt) {
    return txt === "3" ? "Declined" :
           txt === "2" ? "Approved" : "Pending"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2016-10-11 13:10:26</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>mail@yahoo.com</td>
    <td>number</td>
    <td class="status" value="3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2016-10-11 13:10:26</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>mail@yahoo.com</td>
    <td>number</td>
    <td class="status" value="2">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2016-10-11 13:10:26</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>mail@yahoo.com</td>
    <td>number</td>
    <td class="status" value="0">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You save my day, sir!
Thanks a lots.. very thanks :)